# Network Data Packing

Tags: c++, networking, packets, packing

I was searching for a way to efficiently pack my data in order to send them over a network.
I found a topic which suggested a way : http://www.sdltutorials.com/cpp-tip-packing-data

And I've also seen it being used in commercial applications. So I decided to give it a try, but the results weren't what I expected.

1. First of all , the whole point of "packing" your data is to save bytes. But I don't think that  the algorithm mentioned above is saving bytes at all.
   Because , without packing ... The server would send 4 bytes (Data) , after the packing the server sends a character array , 4 bytes long ... So it's pointless.
2. Aside from that , why would someone add 0xFF , it doesn't do anything at all.

The code snippet found in the tutorial mentioned above:

```
    unsigned char Buffer[3];
    unsigned int Data = 1024;
    unsigned int UpackedData;
    Buffer[0] = (Data >> 24) & 0xFF;
    Buffer[1] = (Data >> 12) & 0xFF;
    Buffer[2] = (Data >> 8) & 0xFF;
    Buffer[3] = (Data ) & 0xFF;
    UnpackedData = (Buffer[0] << 24) | (Buffer[1] << 12) | (Buffer[2] << 8) | (Buffer[3] & 0xFF);
```

Result:
0040 // 4 bytes long character
1024 // 4 bytes long

Comment: Hola there. I think there is some confusion on what the purpose of my post is -- and perhaps it's partly my fault. The point is to pack some other data, like an integer, into a char to send over a network. It doesn't mean you are going to save bytes / compress data. It's simply packing one data type into another. Also, bug mentioned below has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The `& 0xFF` is to make sure it's between 0 and 255.

I wouldn't place too much credence in that posting; aside from your objection, the code contains an obvious mistake. `Buffer` is only 3 elements long, but the code stores data in 4 elements.

Comment: Thank yew. Thank yew verra much.

Answer (score 3):

For integers a simple method I found often useful is BER encoding. Basically for an unsigned integer you write 7 bits for each byte, using the 8th bit to mark if another byte is needed

```
void berPack(unsigned x, std::vector<unsigned char>& out)
{
    while (x >= 128)
    {
        out.push_back(128 + (x & 127)); // write 7 bits, 8th=1 -> more needed
        x >>= 7;
    }
    out.push_back(x); // Write last bits (8th=0 -> this ends the number)
}
```

for a signed integer you encode the sign in the least significant bit and the use the same encoding as before

```
void berPack(int x, std::vector<unsigned char>& out)
{
    if (x < 0) berPack((unsigned(-x) << 1) + 1, out);
          else berPack((unsigned(x) << 1), out);
}
```

With this approach small numbers will use less space. Another advantage is that this encoding is already architecture-neutral (i.e. data will be understood correctly independently on the endian-ness of the system) and that the same format can handle different integer sizes and you can send data from a 32 bit system to a 64 bit system without problems (assuming of course that the values themselves are not overflowing).

The price to pay is that for example unsigned values from 268435456 (1 << 28) to 4294967295 ((1 << 32) - 1) will require 5 bytes instead of 4 bytes of standard fixed 4-bytes packing.

Comment: This is obviously ALWAYS true. So there's no point in stating it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's necessarily "obvious".  It's obvious to me and you, but it may not be to someone who's never thought about compression schemes or information theory in detail.

Comment: Can BER encoding be applied to a SHORT so small numbers will use even less space?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Fair enough. I've added a last section explaining the extra cost.

Comment: @Christian: with BER encoding a number less than 128 will take just one byte no matter if it's a `unsigned long long` or a `short` because the encoding depends on the value, not on the bit size of the variable. One could implement a BER encoding based on a different bit chunking (e.g. using 4 bits so that numbers 0..7 can take only half a byte). Also many other variations are of course possibile but they're more complex to implement.

Answer (score 2):

1. Another reason for packing is to enforce a consistent structure, so that data written by one machine can be reliably read by another.
2. It's not "adding"; it's performing a bitwise-AND in order to mask out the LSB (least-significant byte).  But it doesn't look necessary here.

Comment: I don't think he meant adding as in `+`. I think he meant adding as in adding the `& 0xFF` to the end.

Comment: But for MSG (server<->client) messages , which are both packed and upacked at both sides. Isn't it poinless? It doesn't reduce the bytes , so it's no packing. Maybe the author is wrong, or i simply misunderstood something. Eitherway, is there an efficient way to pack my data and send them over the network with their physical size reduced?

Comment: @Christian: "Packing" doesn't necessarily mean "compressing".  It just means "arranging things into bytes".

Comment: @Marlon Yeah, that's what I meant. But that's not the point of the topic.